# Arduino String problem

Tags: arduino-uno

Hello I am using the u8glib library to draw text on the string but it keeps giving me an error with the string

```c
 String name1 = "";
 ...
 void draw(){
  u8g.setFont(u8g_font_micro);
  u8g.drawStr(22, 37, name1);
 }
```

why dosnt this work?

Here is the error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\U8glib/U8glib.h:200:16: note:
>   no known conversion for argument 3 from 'int' to 'const
>   __FlashStringHelper*' no matching function for call to 'U8GLIB_PCD8544::drawStr(int, int, String&)'

Answer (score 2):

String is evil and should be avoided at all costs (http://hacking.majenko.co.uk/the-evils-of-arduino-strings)

The author of u8glib knows that and has refused (quite rightly) to implement them.

You should not use String either.  If you really *must* for some obscure reason then you will have to pass the internal "C string" reference to the `drawStr` function instead of the whole String object:

```
u8g.drawStr(22, 37, name1.c_str());
```

The *only* reason people use String is because they are too lazy to learn the proper way of handling textual data in C.

Comment: The link is broken: *"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at hacking.majenko.co.uk."*

Comment: Re *"String is evil"*: I have come to the same conclusion, after some pain. It was there all along, but it didn't really show up until now. It was used in formatting of error reporting going to the serial port and as the frequency of (spurious, harmless) errors increased due to some changes to the system, occasional hard freezes was the result. Strangely, it was dependent on the Serial Monitor (or another terminal, like [Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen)) being open/connected... It being open made the error nearly 100% reproducible.

Comment: cont' - That was with an [Arduino Leonardo](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-leonardo-with-headers).

Comment: If they shouldn't use String, what should they use instead? Perhaps add something to this effect to the answer? And/or a reference to [this answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/86250/).

Answer (score 0):

[Like the documentation says](https://github.com/olikraus/u8glib/wiki/userreference#drawstr), that method doesn't take a `String` object. Call the `c_str()` method of the `String` object and pass that instead.

Comment: what do you mean, what should I put in my arduino code? I looked at the documentation and i cant see a c_str() method

Comment: `name1.c_str()`