# What's is the best way to convert std::string to String?

Tags: c++, esp32, string

Pardon me, I am a novice programmer. I was trying to use the toInt() function for a std::string but I noticed that toInt() only works for the String class. So, I have an std::string sliderValue and wanted to convert it to the String class so I could use the toInt() function. [Here](https://www.techiedelight.com/convert-std-string-char-cpp/), I found a way that seemed to pacify Intellisense, vMicro, and building. I did:

```
String convertValue = strcpy(new char[sliderValue.length() + 1], sliderValue.c_str());
```

so I could do:

```
ledcWrite(ledChannel, convertValue.toInt()  * (10.24));
```

Is there a better way to do this or am I on point? Also, I'd love to get insight in what I'm doing, if possible. Thanks folks!

P.S. I looked up [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/56365/arduino-convert-stdstring-to-string) here at arduino stackexchange, and it didn't seem to provide a solution specific to my question.

Comment: If you have `std::string`, chances are you also have [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to use `String` (for anything, generally...). Instead you can either (if you have it) use `std::stoi()` or use `strtol()` on the `c_str` of the string.

```cpp
ledcWrite(ledChannel, std::stoi(sliderValue)  * (10.24));
```

Or

```cpp
ledcWrite(ledChannel, strtol(sliderValue.c_str(), NULL, 10)  * (10.24));
```

The former just converts into the latter anyway.